# Why doesn't IndexOf work with StringCompare?

Tags: c#, string-comparison, indexof, currentculture, ignore-case

I get this error

```
    string v = "aeiou";
    foreach(int i in lokacija.Naziv) {
      if(v.indexOf(lokacija.Naziv[i], StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) = -1)
        s+=lokacija.Naziv[i];
    }
```

The error says "cannot convert from System.StringComparison to int". But I know there is an overload of the method indexOf(string) which accepts arguments of the type StringComparison. So how can I resolve this?

Comment: what version of .net?

Comment: I'd guess that `lokacija.Naziv[i]` likely provides a `Char`. [`.IndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) only accepts `StringComparison`s when the 1st argument is a `String`.

Comment: @djomles, did you have the chance to try what I suggested?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski it depends of the .NET Framework used. There **is** such a function in .NET Core 3.1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_IndexOf_System_Char_System_StringComparison_

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should be using `==` for comparison.

Second, all `IndexOf` overloads whose first parameter is a `char`, their second parameter is an `int`. That's why you get that error. In order to use the overload that receives a `StringComparison`, make that first parameter a `string`, like this:

```
if (v.indexOf(lokacija.Naziv[i].ToString(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == -1)
```

BTW, are you trying to remove vowels from a string? I recommend you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32871783/2321042).

Comment: not quite true your second point. In .NET Core we have the overload `char, StringComparision` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_IndexOf_System_Char_System_StringComparison_

Comment: Well, .NET Core Initial release: June 27, 2016, my bad for not knowing the future.

Answer (score 0):

you loop seems strange... did you mean this?

```
foreach(string ssub in lokacija.Naziv) {
  if(v.indexOf(ssub, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) = -1)
    s+=ssub;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Johnathan-Lonowski hit the nail on the head- you are getting [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y(v=vs.110).aspx) version of String.IndexOf, not [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx) one, because you are looking for a character in a string, not an occurrence of one string in another.

Comment: there **is** a function with `(char, ComparisonType)`, in .NET Core